# Get an instance of TabItem's ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `TabControl` tied to a collection of items where each item is supposed to be represented by a normal `TabItem` which hosts a user control, like so:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Items"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This,Path=Files}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type App:MyContext}">
                        <App:Task x:Name="task" Image="{Binding Path=Image}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

The `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<MyContext>`.

I would like to get to each and every `App:Task` generated for each of my `MyContext` instances like so (or similar):

```
foreach (var file in Files)
{
    var container = Items.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(file) as TabItem;
    if (container == null) continue;

    var task = container.Content as Task;
    if (task == null) return;

    // ...
}
```

But the `container.Content` is `MyContext` not `Task`. So I figured I should use:

```
var task = container.ContentTemplate.FindName("task") as Task;
```

But this throws an exception because at this point the `ContentTemplate` does not seem to have been applied yet. How can I force it or get what I want in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why* do you need the UserControl in the first place?

If you need to access something you haven't bound enough properties on your items to the UserControls.

Comment: You have a point and I have found a workaround for my problem by trying a different approach. Still I would like to hear the solution, if one exists.

Comment: @wpwannabe: You would probably need to select it first, and wait for [`ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.statuschanged.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! So if I want to loop over all items (like I've shown in the sample) I have no choice but to repeat this?

Comment: Don't think there is a way around that if you use the containers (which hardly ever is a good idea).